# C# - Binding GridControl to List and manipulating the records in run-time

Tags: c#, list, devexpress, gridcontrol

This is my first question here on the stack overflow, sorry if I did something wrong !!

I'm starting with C# and DevExpress and I'm trying to create an example using the DevExpress GridControl (v.19.2.5.0) with a class that contains some records in a List.

I created a simple project (Windows Forms) and put a GridControl and tried to connect the GridControl to the class (Record.cs/PrototipoViewModel.cs).

The GridControl in designer mode, lists the columns, but in run-time, it is empty.

Where did I go wrong? Or what did I not do to list the records in run-time?

My second question would be, can I insert, update and delete the records in run-time directly in GridControl using a list ?

Class Record.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Prototipo
{
    public class Record
    {
        public DateTime? Data { get; set; }
        public string Cliente { get; set; }
        public string Movimento { get; set; }
        public decimal Valor { get; set; }

        public static List<Record> GetRecords()
        {
            List<Record> people = new List<Record>();

            people.Add(new Record() { Data = new DateTime(2021, 04, 07, 19, 00, 00), Cliente = "Joao", Movimento = "D", Valor = 1000});
            people.Add(new Record() { Data = new DateTime(2021, 04, 07, 19, 30, 00), Cliente = "Maria", Movimento = "D", Valor = 2000 });
            people.Add(new Record() { Data = new DateTime(2021, 04, 07, 20, 00, 00), Cliente = "Jose", Movimento = "D", Valor = 3000 });

            return people;
        }
    }
}
```

Class PrototipoViewModel.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Prototipo
{
    public class PrototipoViewModel
    {
        public PrototipoViewModel()
        {
            this.Records = Record.GetRecords();
        }

        public List<Record> Records { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and Class frmPrototipoMain.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Prototipo
{
    public partial class frmPrototipoMain : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
    {
        public frmPrototipoMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

The project is on in GitHub ( https://github.com/tiago-pimenta/vs_gridcontrol_bind_class )

Thanks

Comment: You can play with Records of List<Record> to insert/update/delete. Further I don't think you bind Records with your Grid control.

Comment: Where do you set the GridControl.DataSource property?

Comment: Thnks for comment @Zeeshanef

Comment: @Brendon In the "Data Sources" tab, I created one of the type "Object" and pointed to the class "PrototypeViewModel" and in the "Choose DataSource" property of the Grid, I selected "recordsBindingSource". It was precisely after this process that the columns appeared in design mode, but did not bring the records

Comment: That isn't sufficient. You need to actually set the GridControl's DataSource property to the List<Record> as well. The designer steps you took simply created the columns and set their FieldName properties for you.

Comment: @Brendon could you explain to me how do i do the rest that is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Well folks, I was able to find where the error was in my code, I thought that setting the "Choose DataSource" property of GridControl would be enough, but the code below was missing:

```
private void frmPrototypeMain_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             gridControl.DataSource = Prototipo.Record.GetRecords();
         }
```

Well, now I just have to solve the problem of allowing GridControl to insert new lines, reading the DevExpress documentation, says to set the "AllowNew" and "AllowRemove" properties to True from the DataSource, and also says that you need to create a class with one property of this required simple type. This class must have an empty default constructor.

My DataSource, only has the property "AllowNew" and is already set to "True", but even so I can't insert new lines in the GridControl.

Is my class the property of this required simple type? Does it have the default constructor empty?

Thank you who helped so far !!!